# Применение паттерна для избежания if-циклов

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, if

Попалась следующая задача для определения нужного паттерна и изменения кода. Дан код :

```
public class КофеАвтомат{
 private boolean включен;
 private boolean чистит;
 private boolean готовитКофе;
 public void нажалВключить() {

if (!включен) {
  включен = true;
 } else if (!чистит && !готовитКофе) {
 включен = false;
   }
 }

public void нажалЧистить() {
  if (включен && !чистит && !готовитКофе) {
    чистит = true;
    читсить();
    чистит= false;
  }
}

public void нажатьГотовитьКофе() {
   if (включен && !чистит && !готовитКофе) {
    готовитКофе = true;
    гретьКофе();
    готовитКофе = false;
   }
}

// private void reinige();
// private void brüheKaffee();
}
```

Задача заключается в определение паттерна, с помощью которого можно иуменьшить количество if-циклов, и сделать код гибким для добавления новых функций кофе-машины, а также легко менять условие циклов (if).

Пришел к выводу , что мне стоит применить паттера Командо и структурировать код по определению. Но смущает момент с шибкостью изменений условий в циклах. Также не совсем ясна разница между паттерном Стратегия и Командо в данном конкретном случае.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Напрашивается State...